# Java: Can't execute external exe with arguments

Tags: java, processbuilder

I’m trying to run an external program with arguments. The program can take different types of arguments, for instance
`avl tip.avl` or `avl < test.ops`

I can get `avl tip.avl` running through

```
try {
    String[] list = {"avl", "test_0.avl"};
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(list);
    pb.command(list);
    final Process p = pb.start();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( p.getInputStream() ) );
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println(ex);
}
```

but when I try

```
String[] list = {"avl", "<", "test_0.ops"};
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(list);
pb.command(list);
final Process p = pb.start();
```

the `"<"` does not get sent as an argument, but as an input after the program runs. `avl < test.ops` works ok when I try it from command line, but cant get it to work through `ProcessBuilder`.

I think `avl tip.avl` works because running `avl tip.avl` is the same as just running `avl` and then typing `tip.avl`. Which is what `ProcessBuilder` seems to be doing actually ...

I assumed the arguments would be passed all at one. What would be the right way of doing what the command prompt input does `avl < test.ops` + ENTER

Comment: what happens if you send it as one string rather than array of them?

Comment: That doesn't work because piping from a file is a shell feature, processbuilder doesn't use a shell, so the < is treated as an argument

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot redirect input like that from Java.  Using `<` is a special shell pipe redirection command.

You will either have to use `processBuilder.getOutputStream()` to write data to the process, or else you can use [redirectInput.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectInput(java.lang.ProcessBuilder.Redirect))

Answer (score 1):

> the `"<"` does not get sent as an argument, but as an input after the program runs

No, that’s not right. It is passed as an argument, just as `test_0.avl` and `test_0.ops` are.

> […] the same as just running `avl` and then typing `tip.avl`

No, that is *never* what happens in the shell. The shell will pass `tip.avl` as the first argument.

That said, it is your shell that special-handles the `<` sign, as it would special-handle `>` and `|`. When you use `ProcessBuilder`, that special handling will not happen. Your second invocation is equivalent to this in the shell:

```
avl '<' test_0.ops
```

This will disable the sepcial meaning of the `<`. That’s not what you wanted here, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you both, the below works as expected.

```
File pipe = new File("test_0.ops");
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("avl");
pb.redirectInput(pipe);
final Process p = pb.start();
```